# When merging two JFrame files github removes one of the files code

Tags: java, github, merge

Hello I have a university project in which There is a netbeans JFrame form file called "gui.java". In the "gui.java" JFrame form file. there are two Main Panels: "userTabPanel" and "adminTabPanel". I built the gui inside "userTabPanel" panel on my PC while my partner built the "adminTabPanel" panel on his PC. Now i wanted to merge the two "gui.java" files together but when i try to merge my partner code with mine it removes all the "userTabPanel" code and only the "adminTabPanel" code remains after the merge and vice versa.

We both have the same base files(project folders).The only difference is the code inside the gui.java files inside the project folders.

Here is a picture of github pull request:
[image]

As you can see it's removing all the user Tab code and adding the admin Tab code. if i merge the opposite way it removes the admin Tab code and adds the user Tab code. is there any solution to this or do we have to make the complete gui first since i can't merge them ?

Comment: Looks like you have largely similar (I'm assuming generated) code. How are you performing the merge? In conflicting files, there's typically a process (`git merge`) to actually determine what parts you wish to keep, and if you are ignoring that (and simply "merging" one) then you may be overwriting it. Similarly you could have one person commit their code, and the other one `pull` the code before commiting.

Comment: @Rogue how can i do "git merge" process do i need to learn git for this or can this be done in Github?

Comment: An IDE will typically have a prompt window you can use to visually perform the merge, but yes, you will need to actually perform the merge properly to do it. git (or your IDE) should prompt you to perform a merge when you attempt to pull the first commit into the local repository that contains the second "chunk" of code you need to commit.